# React - weird behavior with '.unshift()' but not with '.push()' on state array

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I'm trying to make a bidirectional scroll component in React that basically renders chunks of weeks based on the scroll position so if user reaches top past data is rendered and if bottom - future data is rendered.

Here's some very basic code.

```
const [chunks, setChunks] = useState(initChunks);

const handleReachEdge() => {
  const _chunks = chunks.slice();
  const lastChunk = conditionOnReachTop ? _chunks[0] : _chunks[_chunks.length - 1]
  const newChunk = {
    position: conditionOnReachTop ? lastChunk.position - 1 : lastChunk.position + 1; 
   //position is basically my component key
    ...data
  }

  conditionOnReachTop ? _chunks.unshift(newChunk) : _chunks.push(newChunk);
  setChunks(_chunks);
}

const renderChunks = () => {
  return chunks.map(chunk => <SomeComponent key={chunk.position} />
}
```

The position parameters are [..., -2, -1, 0, 1, 2, ...]

My problem is that when data is pushed to the array and then state is set everything works fine - the new component renders and the rest doesn't re-render. When the array is unshifted and then the state is set **all components mapped from that array are re-rendered**, even though I provided unique keys for all of them. They're even React.memo components.

The 'SomeComponent' makes an api call on render so the fact that they all rerender is kinda important.

What am I doing wrong and how can I fix it?

Comment: I don't expect either way should work reliably as you've done some state mutation when you push/unshift into `_chunks` which is a reference to state `chunks` that you save back into state. You never update state with a new array reference.

Comment: @DrewReese Thanks for your reply. I fixed it according to the answer by T.J. Crowder. Unfortunately it didn't fix my issue.

Comment: @WojciechMista - That's unfortunate. Please update your question with a [mcve] demonstrating the problem, ideally a **runnable** one using Stack Snippets (the `[<>]` toolbar button). Stack Snippets support React, including JSX; [here's how to do one](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/338537/).

Comment: *Normally*, changing a question such that it invalidates existing answers is considered poor behavior here (because after all, the person answering answered what was posted). But as the person who posted the (now deleted) answer, I've added the `slice` call to the question. We don't need another "don't modify state directly" answer on the site anyway. :-) But we do need that minimal example.

Comment: I got curious and so I took the code and fixed various typos. [I can't replicate the problem](https://codesandbox.io/s/so-question-62298921-qzepc) (not even without the `slice` call).

Comment: @T.J.Crowder The code I provided was a simplified version of what I have in my app. Thanks for your sandbox, it made me realize what I was doing wrong and I found the source of the issue. When I render components from an array I save refs of their wrapper <div> to an array using index provided by .map, for example ref={ref => refArray[i] = {offsetTop: ref.offsetTop}. So adding components via push works fine because it just adds a new component at the end of the array but unshift changes all indexes in the array and it causes a rerender of all of them for some reason.